# handle database migrations/upgrades with django

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, database, django

How can I get django to handle upgrading/migration of database schema versions automatically? Currently, whenever I make a schema change that modifies an existing part of the schema, running `syncdb` fails to make the changes, so I have to manually drop the tables and re-run `syncdb`.

Comment: I've revised the question, is it possible to take off hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[south](http://south.aeracode.org/) is de facto standard for django.

*(it even will be included natively in django 1.7, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209583/699864))*

Comment: good to know that will be native in 1.7! I wonder how long that will be until its released...